# Why was House cancelled?

Tags: house, cancellation

I feel like *House* is one of those shows that could continue forever. Why was it cancelled?

Comment: I don't have time right now to turn this into an answer, but if someone else does that's cool with me, but here is an article about it from TV Line: https://www.tvguide.com/news/house-cancellation-1043356/

Comment: "I want this show to continue forever" is a **very** dangerous statement to make. Observe the infamous decline in quality of *The Simpsons*, or *Fairly Odd Parents*, or *Dexter*, and ask yourself whether you want that to happen to your own favourite show. Or to paraphrase *Jurassic Park*: "Your executives were so preoccupied with whether they *could*, they didn't stop to think whether they *should*."

Comment: @F1Krazy true, I used to think "I wish _X_ continued forever" but then seeing how some of my favorite shows declined in quality after too long I also prefer to have a good wrap up a la Breaking Bad.

Comment: Arguably they already pushed one season too much. I don't think I would call a series not overextending itself too much as being "cancelled".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long story short, because of money.

[According to this article](https://www.tvguide.com/news/house-cancellation-1043356/) Universal TV wanted to produce a new season but Fox network was spending $5 million per episode and wanted a cut in the show's license before renewing. They couldn't agree on an amount.

> "Universal came off as aggressive," one exec says. "It was such a big gap that [Fox] didn't pursue the discussions." Universal insiders say the studio was surprised by the decision and had been willing to work out a compromise.

After that there were some budget cuts, but the negotiations were dragged for too long and Fox had other shows performing well enough to let House go.

> Fox execs and (David) Shore (executive producer) agreed to wrap things up, and on February 8, the cast and crew were informed. By then, Shore had made his peace with the decision. "He was interested in another year," says an insider. "But he wanted to go out as strong as possible."